# OpenSSl is not available. Install OpenSSL and rebuild Ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, chromebook

I bought a new chromebook, downloaded ruby and rbenv but I cannot download open SSL and I don't know how to since I am trying 'gem install rails'

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
OpenSSl is not available. Install OpenSSL and rebuild Ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources

Researching online but I am still confused as there is no direct download link for chromebook/linux

Comment: No experience doing this but googling shows a few options: 1) The most official and supported ways are provided [Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/containers_and_vms.md) 2) Put Chromebook in [Developer Mode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/debug_buttons.md#firmware-keyboard-interface) and then install a package manager like [chromebrew](https://github.com/chromebrew/chromebrew) or use [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) to setup a chroot